# Triple integral too close together

Tags: amsmath, integral

I'm trying to write a triple integral with `\iiint`, but it feels like it's too close together

[image]

While doing it with `\int\int\int` it's too spaced apart. Is there any way to change this?

Edit: I wanted something a little bit more like this

[image]

Edit 2: It's the esint package that was causing it.

Comment: `amsmath` is a kind of a standard. Of course, you can customize with negative spaces `\int\!\int\!\int`

Comment: I get the second screenshot when compiling `\iiint_{E}`. If I have triple `\int`, they are really far apart, as I understand, because their boxes don't get overlapped but stick to one another, which I suppose is correct. On the other hand, if I use `\mkern-9mu` between each `\int`, I get the same result as `\iiint_{E}`.

Comment: @BlackMild this gives the same result as `\int\int\int` unfortunately.

Comment: @Celdor using `\mkern-9mu` works. Do you have any idea why I'm having a different output compared to yours?

Comment: @TulioAlves `\!` is only `-3mu` so the effect is very small. As to your question, I have no idea why you would have a different output, sorry.

Comment: Which math font are you using?

Comment: Please, add an example of code. Are you perhaps using `unicode-math`?

Comment: I'm using amsmath, but after some time changing the code and packages I found it was esint that was causing the integrals to be so obnoxiously close together. I don't even know why I was using tbh...

Comment: I believe without adding `MWE`, you should not get proper suggestion....So Please add it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you are using `esint` that defines special glyphs for the multiple integrals.

You can easily revert to the `amsmath` spacing, keeping the additional `esint` integral symbols.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{esint}

\renewcommand{\iint}{\DOTSI\MultiIntegral{2}}
\renewcommand{\iiint}{\DOTSI\MultiIntegral{3}}
\renewcommand{\iiiint}{\DOTSI\MultiIntegral{4}}
\renewcommand{\idotsint}{\DOTSI\MultiIntegral{0}}


\begin{document}

\[
\int_E \quad
\iint_E \quad
\iiint_E \quad
\iiiint_E \quad
\idotsint_E
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]